# Add Dynamic class name in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a service which returns a response "state" , state can be either 'checkout','delivered','pending'. I need to add icon according to this state, im new for angular , and much appreciate if some one can direct me to a method which will help me to do this task.

Comment: `ng-class="state"`?  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: `<img ng-src="/images/{{state}}.png"/>` ? At least try something, and show us what you tried. This is basic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways that you could achieve this:

**1.** You could use a controller method to help determine the state and call if from your view:

**Controller**:

```
$scope.applyClass = function(myObj) {
    if (myObj.state === 'checkout') {
        return 'checkout-class';
    } else if (myObj.state === 'delivered'){
        return 'delivered-class'
    } else if (myObj.state === 'pending'){
        return 'pending-class';
    }
}
```

**View**:

```
<div ng-class="applyClass(myObj)">...</div>
```

**2.** Alternatively, you could also do it without a controller by just string interpolate the object's state (assuming that myObj.state always returns either checkout, delivered, or pending):

```
<div ng-class="{{myObj.state}}-class">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution could be like

```
controller("testCtrl",function($scope,someService){
 $scope.state = someService.state();
  })
```

view:

```
<div class="{{state}}-class">...</div>
```